# OpenFileDialog fails on Win7

Tags: wix, wix3.5

My installer needs to open a file browse dialog. As there is no file browse dialog provided by WIX I have written a C# dll containing a method to invoke the standard OpenFileDialog when called by a Custom Action. However while this works fine in Win2003 the Custom Action just hangs when run on Windows 7. It seems to get as far as the ShowDialog() call then stop. As a test I have written a separate Windows Forms app with a single dialog and button to invoke the OpenFileDialog and, as expected, that works fine. I just can't get the OpenFileDialog to appear from within my msi!

I suspect it may be a security thing so I ran the installer from msiexec opened as Administrator but with no difference!

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
  // create a new thread with appropriate apartment state to launch UI 
  OpenFileDialog fileBrowser = new OpenFileDialog(); 
  Thread worker = new Thread(fileBrowser.Show); 
  worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  // <-- here is the magic code 
  worker.Start(); 
  worker.Join();
```

Answer (score 0):

When I attempted this I found it was popping up *behind* the other MSI windows. Until I figured this out, it looked just like a hang.

For this and a whole heap of other reasons, I ended up writing a bespoke install mechanism and ditching MSI. Much friendlier on the user and their system in the end.